# ReactJS Modal opening multiple times when in a Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

Hi I am playing around with ReactJS, and found this awesome Modal Component to open Videoes in a Modal, but when I put the Modal inside a loop with multiple links and open the modal, it open like 5 times if I have 5 links. What do I do wrong?

**Modal Component: https://github.com/appleple/react-modal-video**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'enter code here
import ModalVideo from 'react-modal-video'

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this)
  }

  openModal () {
    this.setState({isOpen: true})
  }

      render () {
        return (
          <div>
            <ModalVideo channel='youtube' isOpen={this.state.isOpen} videoId='L61p2uyiMSo' />
            <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

**My Loop with the Modal Component Inside:**

```
render(){
    return(
            <div>
                {(this.props.frag.all == null) ? null :
                  this.props.frag.all.map((frags, i) => {
                  return (
                  <li key={frags.id} className="group" id="" style={{width: 'calc(13% - 30px)'}}>
                    <ModalVideo channel='youtube' isOpen={this.state.isOpen} videoId='{frags.url}' />
                      <button onClick= {this.openModal.bind(this)}>Open</button>
                  </li>
                )})
              }
          </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that each ModalComponent uses the same state property `isOpen` so when you click on any link it sets this property and each ModalComponent becomes open. You should use unique property for each modal (you can use poperty which you already uses as `key`).

```
<li key={frags.id} className="group" id="" style={{width: 'calc(13% - 30px)'}}>
    <ModalVideo channel='youtube' isOpen={this.state.isOpen[frags.id]} videoId='{frags.url}' />
    <button onClick= {this.openModal.bind(this, frags.id)}>Open</button>
 </li>
```

And your method:

```
 openModal (id) {
    this.setState({
       isOpen: {
          [id]: true
       }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Just tried your idea, it worked perfectly, it opens and closes with no issues! And thanks for the explanation, I think I almost got it now! xD

Answer (score 0):

Reason is, you are using single `state` variable to maintain `open/close` status of `modal`, it will work properly for one, but in case of multiple modals, you have to use multiple state values to maintain the statuses, Use this:

Define `isOpen` as an `array` in state:

```
this.state= {
    isOpen=[],
}
```

Use this method to `change` the status of any particular `modal`:

```
openModal(index){
    let isOpen = this.state.isOpen.slice();
    isOpen[index] = true;
    this.setState({isOpen});
}
```

`Bind` the `index` of each modal in `onClick` method:

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {(this.props.frag.all == null) ? null :
              this.props.frag.all.map((frags, i) => {
              return (
              <li key={frags.id} className="group" id="" style={{width: 'calc(13% - 30px)'}}>
                <ModalVideo channel='youtube' isOpen={this.state.isOpen[i] || false} videoId='{frags.url}' />
                  <button onClick= {this.openModal.bind(this,i)}>Open</button>
              </li>
            )})
          }
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and really great explanation! It worked kind of, the first modal opens perfeclty, but when I go and open the next one it Opens two modals, like the new modal and the previuos. Do you have any clue why? :)

Answer (score 0):

Modals in a loop are a bit complicated because they need a unique key for each row. Making the modal work without duplicating it is another challenge. The first mistake many of us make is including the modal within the loop. To prevent the duplication of the modal we need to make it fully dynamically. I have included a full example without having to duplicate the modal inside of the loop. I hope that helps

here is a full example

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Alert, Input, Modal, ModalBody, ModalFooter, ModalHeader } from 'reactstrap';

class History extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        userHistory: [{'id': 1, 'test': 'this is a test'}, {'id': 2, 'test': 'this is a test2'}, {'id': 3, 'test': 'this is a test3'}],
            showLog: false,
            logID: null
        }
    }

    render() 
    {
        const history = this.state.userHistory.map( (ticket, key) =>
        {
            return (
                <tr key={key}>
                    <td>{ticket.test}</td>
                    <td>{ticket.id ? <Button  color="info" onClick={() => this.setState({logID:                          ticket.id, showLog: true})}>View</Button> : ''}</td>
                </tr>
            ) 
        });

        return (
            <div className="card-body">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr> 
                            <th>test</th>
                            <th>modal</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {history}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                    
                <Modal id={this.state.logID} isOpen={this.state.showLog} fade="false"  toggle={() => this.setState({showLog: false})}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={() => this.setState({showLog: false})}>@jerryurenaa is awesome :D</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>   
                        <p>Modal Number: {this.state.logID}</p>                     
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({showLog: false})}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default History;
```